# Cant save fig with plotnine

Tags: python, save, plotnine

I have a plot that I am trying to save with plotnine.

```
w = 10
h = 5    

p9.ggsave(heatmap,plotName, width=w, height= h, dpi=300, limitsize=False)
```

For some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\s2997324\Bond University\Research Data - ENHANCE_Survey\DataExtraction\ENHANCESurvey\ENHANCESurvey\ENHANCESurveyAnalysis\Script2Analysis.ipynb Cell 57 line 8
83 w = 10
84 h = 5
86 p9.ggsave(heatmap,plotName, width=w, height= h, dpi=300, limitsize=False)

File c:\Users\s2997324\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotnine\ggplot.py:644, in ggplot.save(self, filename, format, path, width, height, units, dpi, limitsize, verbose, **kwargs)
596 def save(
597     self,
598     filename: Union[str, Path] | None = None,
   (...)
607     **kwargs: Any,
608 ):
609     """
610     Save a ggplot object as an image file
611 
   (...)
642         Additional arguments to pass to matplotlib `savefig()`.
643     """
644     sv = self.save_helper(
645         filename=filename,
646         format=format,
647         path=path,
648         width=width,
...
336     ar.sort()
337     aux = ar
338 mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong as it worked the other day...

I've tried a few different ways of saving but it hasn't worked.

Comment: `error` message indicates that you are passing `string` values `w` and `h`, they should be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error carefully.

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

There happens some forbidden comparison between different data types.
Most likely you pass some string as an argument. Even though python is not an explicitly type language, comparison between different data types would end up in error ("Fail fast" principle) instead of trying to continue with some behavior (as it is in Javascript for example).